# Gson serialization: how to cast generic class and generic data inside it?

Tags: java, generics, gson

An example to make it clearer:

```
public class GsonDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        DataContainer<ExtendedData> dataContainer = new DataContainer<ExtendedData>();
        dataContainer.data = new ExtendedData();
        dataContainer.data.baseData = "base_data";
        dataContainer.data.extraData = "extra_data";

        String json = gson.toJson(dataContainer); // {"data":{"extraData":"extra_data","baseData":"base_data"}}
        System.out.println(json);

        json = gson.toJson(dataContainer, new TypeToken<DataContainer<Data>>() {}.getType());
        System.out.println(json); // i don't want 'extraData' here. Why it steel serializing?
    }

}
```

And data classes that I use:

```
class DataContainer<D extends Data> {
    D data;
}

class Data {
    String baseData;
}

class ExtendedData extends Data {
    String extraData;
}
```

I want to cast `DataContainer<ExtendedData>` to `DataContainer<Data>` and serialize it without `extraData`. I can't actually cast `DataContainer<ExtendedData>`:

```
DataContainer<Data> castedDataContainer = (DataContainer<Data>) dataContainer; // Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'DataContainer<ExtendedData>' to 'DataContainer<Data>'
```

Result, that I expect after instructions TypeToken: `{"data":{"baseData":"base_data"}}`

But `extraData` is steel serializing. What did I wrong?

Comment: I would _never_ expect a simple cast to make a difference here.  I'd expect you'd need to do an explicit copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gson uses reflection while serializing data so a cast won't change anything.

What you want is to control which fields get serialized. You have several alternatives for that:

- [Mark the fields `transient`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#excludeFieldsWithModifiers-int...-).
- [Use the `@Expose` annotation and mark only the fields you want to serialize](http://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation--).
- [Use a custom adapter](http://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#registerTypeAdapter-java.lang.reflect.Type-java.lang.Object-).

The last one allows you to act dinamically so it is the most flexible.

Comment: Yep, I also think about `custom adapter` and it looks like most right way.